# How to call a controller action inside other Controller in Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, controllers, action

I have a form with text fields and one image file . I want to upload the image and next save the form information in the database.
I have two actions : Create and UploadImage.
I want to call the execute method of UploadImage action in the execute method of Create.
The idea is upload the file first and next create the fields.

It is possible to inject the UploadAction in my Create and call the execute method of UploadAction in the execute method of Create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I's not a good idea to call controller actions inside other controller actions. Not sure if it's even possible. May be.
But here is what you can do.
Create a separate class that handles the image upload that should not me a controller.
This class should receive some parameters and work with those.
In the UploadImage controller, read the files that are being uploaded and pass them to your class as the parameters I mentioned above.
This way you can use your upload class in the UploadImage controller and in any other controller you like.

Comment: I already try this , i create a class not extend of Action, just a normal php class  with a method call upload , but when i call this method in the controller action create dont get the  uploader value in $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['postImage' => 'name']); , is empty always

Answer (score 0):

I kind of agree with Marius, but you *can* use the _redirect method in your controller to point to another controller and pass arguments:

[image]

Comment: wouldn't this make a redirect in the browser?

Comment: Do you have an example when you execute a Controller action and redirect to other controller action after complete the first action?

Comment: This will redirect in the browser, so take it for what it's worth.  Here's an example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Controller/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Delete.php#L33

Comment: I iam calling the action in ajax with jquery. is working in ajax too?

Comment: It should work as long as you hit the action path. It's hard to say without looking at your controller's code

Comment: I don´t understand how to call another controller action .this is my controller UploadFile , i wanto to call the execute method of other action call create after upload: https://gist.github.com/andresfranco/9639eccab2c21021dca4641e2ab33389

Comment: I still think @Marius has the right idea here. You should delegate additional logic to another class (like a model or a helper), but try this out and see if it works:

`$this->_redirect('frontname/controller/action', $result_data)`
Under line 59 in your link.

You need to figure out what the frontname/controller/action is. If the action class is in the SAME directory, then try */*/UploadAction (or whatever your class's name is).